# how to use TRAMP to modify a file on a VM which is on a remote machine?

Tags: emacs, tramp

Here is the scenario: I need to work on a VM, but the VM is on a remote machine. I dont want to set up emacs configurations in that VM. I hope to use my local emacs to edit files on that VM.
I dont know how to do it? I'll appreciate your answer.

Comment: It depends how everything is configured. Can you currently SSH directly to the VM? If not, can you SSH to the remote host machine and then SSH from the host machine to the VM?

Comment: I can ssh to the remote host, then use command `virconsole vm` to start a vm.

Comment: Wait, so the VM isn't even running yet? Once you start it, how do you connect to it?

Comment: First, I ssh to remote machine and virconsole vm to start a vm. Then I enter the virtual machine automaticlly and i am able to run commands.

Comment: I'm not having much success even searching for a command called `virconsole`. What virtualization platform are you using?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know yet. This is set by prof. Does virtualization platform matter? VM has its own network services. I just find a way: just directly ssh to vm. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The virtualization platform _does_ matter if you want to start the VM from Emacs. It might also impact the ways you can connect to a running VM. However, as I suggested in my first comment, if you can SSH directly to the VM there is a much simpler option (which you have now discovered).

Comment: If you can ssh directly to the VM, you could use user name + host (or IP address) of that command also for Tramp. Say you apply `ssh -l joe 1.2.3.4`, then you could open in Emacs `C-x C-f /ssh:joe@1.2.3.4:/path/to/file`.